# How to suppress the "Quick Compare" dialog window when running from command line?

Tags: command-line-arguments, beyondcompare

When I use `Process.Start()` in my .NET app to open two text files in Beyond Compare, the Quick Compare dialog box pops up.  I want to suppress this and have it go straight into text compare mode.

It looks like the command line switch `/filefiewer="Text Compare"` is what I'm looking for, but it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the Quick Compare dialog in Beyond Compare 4, open **Tools > Options**. In the **Startup** section, uncheck **When starting with file comparison, show quick compare dialog**.

Beyond Compare doesn't provide a way to disable the Quick Compare dialog with a command line switch.